# How does Go allocate memory in make or new calls?

Tags: memory, memory-management, go, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I create a new slice or struct with a make or new call:

```
s := make([]int64, 10, 100)
o := new(MyStruct)
```

How much memory does Go allocate with a memory allocation system call? Does it pre-allocate memory, so that subsequent calls don't trigger new system calls?

I am asking this because I need to allocate memory frequently in my code. I am not sure if I need to implement a memory allocater myself, or if I can depend on Go to do the dirty work. And if Go does pre-allocate memory, can I customize the chunk size for allocation?

I write some experiment code in Go, and run the code under strace, but I do not understand what Go does with the mmap system calls:

```
mmap(0xc000000000, 65536, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc000000000
munmap(0xc000000000, 65536)             = 0
mmap(NULL, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efdd1017000
mmap(0xc208000000, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc208000000
mmap(0xc207ff0000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc207ff0000
mmap(0xc000000000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc000000000
mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efdd1007000
mmap(NULL, 1439992, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efdd0ea7000
```

Comment: You can depend on Go to do the dirty work. It calls out to the system to get more than just what you're allocating for small `make`/`new` calls. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/mem_linux.go might be a starting point if you want details. But generally, I think you want to build out your product, then let the profile tell you what's slow.

Comment: Quick question: does Go assign slots of different sizes in reserved memory, to avoid fragmentation? Maybe I need to read the source ...

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/malloc.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might suffer from the "premature optimization" syndrome here. The language spec says *nothing* about how exactly the memory allocated by `make()` will be allocated.

For instance, a conforming implementation of Go might perform thorough analyzis of the function which does `make([]foo, ...)` and prove that:

1. The slice value returned does not escape the function's scope.
2. `append()` is not called on this slice value.
3. The slice value it not passed to any called function.

In this case, the slice's backing store might be allocated right on the stack.

Sure I'm exaggregating but again, the semantics of this are not declared in the language specification.  And there are currently two mature Go implementations (that one originated from Google, dubbed `gc`, and `gccgo`) with more to come (`llvmgo` seems like having a good chances to live up), and they all have their peculiarities.

So please consider reading up on `pprof` and Go profiling in general, and do profile sample (but real) code.

Searching [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) for the words "profile", "profiling", "heap AND profile", "CPU AND profile" and "pprof" will provide lots of insight on it to you.

Consider also [this](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) and [this](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/22/simple-profiling-package-moved-updated).

Comment: FYI I am trying to implement a cache server, so memory management is not premature optimization.

Comment: @NeoWang, then you might be interested in [`sync.Pool`](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2ap67l/when_to_use_syncpool_and_when_not_to/) or [external memory pools](http://blog.golang.org/qihoo) or [internal memory pools](https://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go/).

Comment: @NeoWang, in general, I highly advise you to ask a question on the mailing list, explicitly mentioning your task and soliciting comments. SO is a wrong medium for such kind of research, really.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/groupcache is a library from the author of memcache, with different design goals.