# How to determine available memory before a make() statement

Tags: go

In Go, when using a make statement,
for example, allocating megabytes of memory

```
    make([]byte, 1024*1024*d)
```

Is there a way to determine how much memory is free, before asking for more memory?

Comment: No, and it would not help if there were. Redesign your solution.

Comment: No. What is available to use is up to the kernel, and may change at the moment you request it.

Comment: Also note that kernels of some popular operating systems will lie to your process about the real amount of the available memory anyway -- this is called ["overcommitting"](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+overcommit).

Comment: Oh, and while we're at it, IUUC the reference Go implemetation (dubbed `gc`, that one which originates from Google -- as opposed to `gccgo` which is a part of GCC) uses the so-called "arena" allocation when it asks the OS to "reserve" a huge pile of contiguous memory and then uses this chunk for allocation -- see [this code](https://golang.org/src/runtime/malloc.go) starting from line 231. Basically that's why even small Go programs appears as using lots of *virtual* memory while they use just moderate amount of physical memory.

Comment: ...continuing with the topic, you might consider implementing a second-order allocator for your needs (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31561221/720999) for further pointers, and don't forget to check out comments there as well) or use a ready-made one, like [`go-slab`](https://github.com/couchbase/go-slab).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your input.

I have decided to use a Max_Memory configuration option, since the use case for this is to utilize n Megabytes of memory up to about 75% max available, on test servers, which are only running this application, as a way to trigger autoscaling in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You can use the [gopsutil](https://godoc.org/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/mem) package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/mem"
)

func main() {
    vm, err := mem.VirtualMemory()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Total:%d, Available:%d, Used:%d", vm.Total, vm.Available, vm.Used)
}
```

There are also lots of ways to get this information that are OS-specific. None of them are perfect, but they'll give you something.

You could also have Max Memory as a configuration variable and use: http://godoc.org/runtime#MemStats.

Comment: The relationship between what `mem.VirtualMemory` reports and how big a size you can pass to `make` without it failing is tenuous at best. Also note that virtual memory is often a *lot* larger than physical memory.

Comment: `vm.Available` has no real bearing on whether you can allocate or not. *If* the server has no swap, and *if* the server has overcommit off, and nothing changes between the time you check and the time you request memory, and the `make` call causes the allocation arena to expand, and the kernel doesn't sacrifice another process for you in the meantime, `vm.Available` *might* correlate with running out of memory.